# PHP Callback which doesn't take a method as an argument

Tags: php

I want to set a callback that simply creates an instance of a class and implements the default constructor. How do I do this?

I know you create an array if you want to call a method of a class after it is instantiated, such as `array(new Order(), "runOrder")`, but I don't want to pass a second argument (method name), as the constructor handles this.

Comment: What software is this callback part of?

Comment: It's for a wordpress hook. When plugins are loaded, I want the callback to instantiate my class

Answer (score 0):

php version?

For php5.3 you can do this:

```
$callable = function(){return new Order();};
```